# Как компактно переписать обявление массива?

Tags: массивы, javascript

Данное выражение выдаёт ошибку. Как надо грамотно объявить массив (как можно компактнее)?

```
var keyvals = {
    {
        "title", "this.$title$"
    }, {
        "minicourl", "this.$minicourl$"
    }, {
        "icourl", "this.$icourl$"
    }, {
        "posX", "this.$posX$"
    }, {
        "posY", "this.$posY$"
    }, {
        "width", "this.$width$"
    }, {
        "height", "this.$height$"
    }, {
        "resizable", "this.$resizable$"
    }, {
        "scrollable", "this.$scrollable$"
    }, {
        "fullscreened", "this.$fullscreened$"
    }, {
        "minimized", "this.$minimized$"
    },
}
```

Я хочу впоследствии перебрать keyvals как массив так:

```
for (var i in keyvals) {
    if (parameters.hasOwnProperty(keyvals[i][0]) {
        eval(keyvals[i][1] + "=parameters[" + keyvals[i][0] + "]");
        alert(keyvals[i][1] + "=parameters[" + keyvals[i][0] + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не масив, а объект.

Comment: Я не сказал, я хочу создать многомерный массив. Как это сделать, чтоб например `keyvals[2][1]` возвращал "`this.$icourl$`"?

Comment: Как вы ставите невидимые запятые? P.S. ХэшКод всё исправил=(

Comment: Я думаю, запятые написаны молоком, чтобы враг не догадался.
`[['многомерный', 'массив', 'а'], ['не', 'объект', 'прочитайте'], ['уже', 'что-нибудь', 'про'], ['JavaScript', 42, null]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно синтаксису объявления и инициализации **массива**

```
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < items[i].length; j++)
        alert(items[i][j]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то я уже забыл элементарный синтаксис!

Answer (score 0):

Или если количество значений равны параметрам

```
var obj = { param : ['width', 'height', 'position'], value : [200, 500, 20] }

for(var i in obj.param)
{
    document.write(obj.param[i] + " = " + obj.value[i] + "<br />");
}
```